# Finding the language generated by a grammar

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

Forgive my lack of knowledge, I am new. I tried to find the language generated by this grammar

```
S → aA | bS | cS | ɛ
A → aA | bB | cS | ɛ
B → aA | bS | ɛ
```

And I came to $\{a^pb^qc^r \mid p \ge 0 \text{ and } q \ge 0 \text{ and } r \ge 0 \}$, but there seems to be a problem as the above language do not have a combination of `abc`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a grammar (or even a regular expression) describes a language that is very hard to describe succintly in other terms. They were devised as means to describe languages in simple, easy to handle, terms.

Sure, there are regular expressions/grammars that describe easy to write down languages; most (in some loose sense of "most") of them don't.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that in this grammar, every non-terminal symbol $X$ has only rules of the form
$$
X \to xX'
$$
where $x$ is a terminal symbol and $X'$ is another non-terminal symbol. **This kind of grammar can be thought of as an NFA.** So you could try writint it down as an NFA.

- There are three states: $S, A, B$.
- $S$ is the initial state. "Final states" correspond to states that have a rule going to $\epsilon$, so that's all the states.
- Now draw the transitions. Starting in state $S$ or $A$, we can read any number of $a$s and $c$s and we stay in states $S$ and $A$. What happens on input $b$ is more interesting.

Once you have the transitions, you can use the procedure to turn an NFA into a regular expression to get a description of the language.